# Windows Phone 8 lens augmented reality

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8, real-time, augmented-reality

I am looking at creating an AR lens for Windows Phone 8. I have played about with lenses and the camera functionality and this is all well and good. I can place icons and pictures on the screen, and manipulate photos which have been taken with the phone. But what I need to do is to be able to read the camera screen in real time before a snap has been taken.

Example: The [Face Lens](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/face-lens/69a2cb09-53e1-477e-a8d7-d3093cff287b) must scan the live screen, checking pixels I assume, to calculate where someone's nose/eyes/etc are to place a clowns nose, or glasses, or whatever, on the live camera screen.

I can do this with a picture, but can't seem to find a way of accessing the current frame in the camera, without taking a picture. Basically, I'll want to scan each pixel each frame that is show in the camera app. I know it's possible, other lenses do this, but where should I look to find the correct method of accessing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly possible. The key to doing this is to make use of the [`PhotoCamera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.photocamera.getpreviewbufferargb32%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) function.

The basic idea is to get the preview buffer from a PhotoCamera object. This is done like this:

```
int[] pixelData = new int[(int)(camera.PreviewResolution.Width * camera.PreviewResolution.Height)];
camera.GetPreviewBufferArgb32(pixelData);
return pixelData;
```

This gets you an uncompressed, .bmp-like picture. You can then access that data to identify features, or to paint additional objects into it.

After modifying the data, push it to a `WriteableBitmap()` for displaying it like this:

```
int[] previewBuffer = GetPreviewBuffer();
pixelData.CopyTo(previewWriteableBitmap.Pixels, 0);
previewWriteableBitmap.Invalidate();
```

**DISCLAIMER:** Most of this was taken from the [Live Camera example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Get-to-Mango-6-Using-a-d25e003d) over at Microsoft. Make sure to also have a look at the [Greyscale Camera example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202982%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), especially for handling events in conjunction with capturing pictures.

Comment: Excellant answer, searched everywhere for a sample of this but came up with nothing. Much appreciated.